# Flat File Upload - automatic process best approach

Tags: c#

I need to fetch a flat file from certain folder and upload it into sql server 2012 express. the file might have million records and while upload I need to log it and capture the error if occured. And the whole process mentioned are automated no manual intervension. what are the best approches to do the requirement.I'm using C#. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to parse the contents of the file or is the file you need to run a *.sql file?

Comment: What kind of file is this? Is it a csv or txt file? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I need to parse the content and update it into sql server 2012. it is a csv file.